# Linux: talk to different devices with same mac on different interfaces

Tags: linux, sockets, unix, networking

I have multiple devices with the same hardware mac address (in factory reset mode) that all call a tftp server in order to get a proper mac.

On the same nic, there would obviously be no way to differentiate the devices, however, i have one device per nic. I evaluated these options to use that fact:

**SO_BINDTODEVICE**

Binding the tftp server on each nic separately would probably still not give me a way to *respond* with a package to the sender, since linux' arp table would be confused about which nic to send that package out from.

**net namespaces**

Linux does not allow bringing physical interfaces into a net namespace. only veths, which again would need to be bridged on the 'host' side, which will probably not work with the same mac appearing on multiple physical nics.

Am i missing an option here?

Comment: Why do factory reset devices have the same MAC? The MAC is a unique identifier by it's very definition, and should be different on each device.

Comment: ARP table does not map MAC to NIC, it maps IP address to MAC. The routing table determines which physical interface (NIC) to use depending on the IP address of the destination.

How are your devices communicating via TFTP (application layer protocol) when they don't have a MAC yet? Are they using static IP addresses?

Comment: @Mvarta they use a fixed ip (192.168.0.1/24) on a default mac that is the same for every device.